# How to open a .CSV file without changing the date format when opened with text file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, format

Since I am new to the VBA ,I have a created a code which enables the user to open a .CSV (system generated) file and delete a column then close it to rename.

When I run the macro it does not effect the .CSV workbook and kept all the date formats `"25/02/2019"` as it is before. But  after running the macro, when I open it with a text file it shows me the date as `"25/02/19" in the text file.How do I solve this matter?

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Rename_workbook()

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim filePath As String

    filePath = ("D:\VBA\")
    fileName = Dir(filePath & "System_567875_20190228*" & ".csv")

    Workbooks.Open (filePath & fileName), local:=True

    Columns("Q:Q").select
    selection.delete   'Deleting column'
    columns("A:Z").Autofit

    Activeworkbook.Close savechanges:=True 'Command to close the "Quality Report*"'
    if fileName <> "" Then 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'renaming closed file'
    fso.Movefile filePath & fileName, filePath & "Quality Report.csv")
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by `open it with a text file`?

Comment: If you're just removing columns, I'd suggest *not* opening it in Excel at all.  This isn't difficult to do with, say, [a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29114590/4088852).

Comment: @ron rosenfeld  can I know where I have done the wrong coding for it to happen like that? It keeps the correct date format in the workbook but different date  format in the text file. Is there any method to make both date format is same.

Comment: I don't know.  I asked you for some more information, but you have chosen to NOT supply it. Therefore I will not be able to help.

Comment: Ohh I am really sorry I was confused. Answer for your question is actually I want to delete a column and save it and rename the file but this csv file is picked up by another macro and extract as a text file therefore I need to open it with a text file manually and to check whether date format is same.This is why I am worrying about the change in the date format in the text file.can you assist me to solve this matter??

Comment: What do you mean by `extract as a text file`?  How are you doing that?

Comment: When right click the workbook there are some options will display so then when I click `open with` and when click `notepad` thats how I check it manually.

Comment: Thank you for that information. When you open a `csv` file, using the `Workbooks.Open` method, Excel will format a date according to your windows regional short date settings (if it can), and would then save it the same way. So if your Windows regional short-date settings are `dd/mm/yy` that would explain everything EXCEPT the format being maintained when you first open the csv file with your code.  (If it can't interpret the date in accord with your computer's settings, it will turn it into a text string).  One is usually better off IMPORTING a csv file to maintain control over formatting.

Comment: If my comment does not provide sufficient information for you to troubleshoot, then I would need more and precise info about all the steps of your process.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld , I have uploaded the complete code(please see the above code) which I use for this task ,your assistance is really appreciated. I am ready to provide more information if required.

Comment: @NilushaM. Put a breakpoint in your macro on the `Columns("Q:Q").select` line and confirm that the date format has not changed after the workbook has been opened but before it has been saved.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld, I found the problem. Actually the file I am refering is generated by a system and also it had multiple date columns ( Column B has current date ` 01.03.19` and column C has previous date `28.02.2019` . First I opened  the workbook with the notepad as text when it had been exctracted to the folder by the system before running the macro.I saw the only today date column date format is `01.03.19`. So then I open the workbook and save it then reopen with notepad and then it had become the correct format which is `01.03.2019`.

Comment: So I think problem is when saving the csv file once its opened.I realize if the workbook is not saved properly the date format will not change from `01.03.19` to `01.03.2019`.  your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: NilushaM. Kindly answer my last question for further assistance. Most likely, you need to set the cell `numberformat` after you open the CSV in Excel.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  the answer for your last question is I set the breakpoint at `Columns("Q:Q").select` and run the macro until that point. But date format was not changed after it had been opened.

Comment: @NilushaM. The date format in the `*.csv` file should be saved by Excel in whatever format the dates are in at the time you execute the `Activeworkbook.Close savechanges:=True` command. So just ensure the date columns have the desired `numberformat` before that code is executed. That code should be what you see examining the csv file with a text editor.  (The dates may get changed to whatever the default Windows regional short-date settings is on the computer when you re-open in Excel)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld,  I got it. Thank you for your kind assistance gave me to sort this out. I will try this with the `Number format` method and check whether it will be solved. Great salute for you sir!